# Heavy Javascript with URLs causes Chrome (DevTools?) to report bad 404's

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, http-status-code-404, developer-tools

A page containing a good load of javascript also contains URLs encoded within the javascript as JS strings.

The problem is that Chrome (or perhaps just it's Developer Tools?) is trying to navigate to these encoded URLs as if they were a part of the HTML.

This only seems to happen when there is a lot of javascript in the page.

The page looks more or less like:

```
<body>
    ....
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        google.maps.event.clearListeners(window.kgmm["marker32"],"click");
        google.maps.event.addListener(window.kgmm["marker32"],"click",clicked);
        window.kgmp["marker54"]=new InfoBox({
            content: "<div class=\"wrapBox\" align=\"left\"><div class=\"imageBox\"><a href=\"#ir_rih\" target=\"_blank\"><span class=\"imageWrap\">"

/* the issue -> */  +"<img src=\"?ajax=1&cls=owAjaxHandler&mtd=thumbnail&amp;i=wp-content\/uploads\/2011\/07\/Bahrija &amp; Fomm ir-rih08.jpg&amp;w=115&amp;h=115\" border=\"0\" alt=\"\"\/><\/"

                    +"span><\/a><\/div><div class=\"specsBox\"><h2>Fomm Ir-Rih<\/h2><div class=\"shortDesc\"><\/div><a class=\"moreInfo\" href=\"#ir_rih\" onclick=\"return krtShowTabByHash(this);\">more details &raquo;<\/a><\/div><\/div>" ,
            disableAutoPan: false,
            maxWidth: 0,
            pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-214, 0),
            zIndex: null
        });
        //]]>
    </script>
    ....
</body>
```

The following is a screenshot on how it looks like in the console:

[image: Screenshot]

---

**Be warned that I'm not looking for a fix**. Please **don't** advise on any way to improve the code.

Rather than a fix, I'm looking for an answer as to **why** this is happening.

**NB:** Wasn't CDATA supposed to stop chrome from parsing the javascript contents as XML elements?

---

**Sample URL causing the issue:**

1. First, go [here](http://www.oneweekholiday.com/business-listings/).
2. Open the console (`Right Click -> Inspect Element -> Console tab`)
3. Click on the second item in the page list, named "Mdina, Rabat, Dingli & Baħrija"
4. Keep looking at the console while the page loads, you should see the aforementioned errors.

**NB:** Someone has marked the question as *"too localized"*. I'd like to point out that that is not true. I've encountered this issue on multiple websites,but never gave it much thought (until now) because the website still works.

Comment: Though doesn't that javascript insert those string into the dom?

Comment: @Jakob - Yes, but when it does, the string is properly formatted. eg, `"a=\"b&gt;\""` becomes `a="b>"`

Comment: Well I can't really see your screenshot all that well but it seemed to have interpreted some of the formatting as well.

Comment: @JakubHampl Do a `Right-Click -> Open Image in new tab`. The formatting you see isn't inside the page. It is Chrome/DevTools that are picking the URLs. Even if the string is not added to DOM, this problem still happens.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Are you expecting it not to try to fetch these URLs at all? Why would it not, assuming that `InfoBox` does in fact insert the `content` into the page?

Comment: @Dan, quite right. When infobox contains that content, the content works correctly (but the errors still show up). But the problem is that even when infobox have not even been actually used, the malformed URLs show up in the console.

Comment: Then please show us code illustrating this. The code you have *does* load the InfoBox.

Comment: Can you replicate this through jsfidle?

Comment: Jakub - When I tried, some time ago, I failed to get it working. Seeing as I'm making a bit of a fuss over it this time, I'm willing to give it another try...

Comment: I couldn't get to isolating the issue in a test case. However, I updated the question with a public URL exhibiting this issue.

Comment: I don't see any errors on the console from loading that page. I'm running Chrome 14.0.835.202 on Mac OS 10.6

Comment: I see them on Windows 7 (32bit), Chrome 14.0.835.202...

Comment: Tried it just now, didn't see any issue like that. Just a few warnings about `[cycle] terminating; too few slides: 0`. Please make some effort to tell us exactly what is going on and how to see it.

Comment: Edited my question with more details...

Answer (score 0):

I'd put dollars to donuts that the problem is your escaping of the `i` url parameter:

```
src=\"?ajax=1&cls=owAjaxHandler&mtd=thumbnail&amp;i=wp-content\/uploads\/2011\/07\/Bahrija &amp; Fomm ir-rih08.jpg&amp;w=115&amp;h=115\"
```

Basically, backslash escaping does not work for URLs.  If you wanted to go to that URL, you'd need to send it as:

```
src=\"?ajax=1&cls=owAjaxHandler&mtd=thumbnail&amp;i=wp-content%2Fuploads%2F2011%2F07%2FBahrija%20%26%20Fomm%20ir-rih08.jpg&amp;w=115&amp;h=115\"
```

---

Chris Edit: Decoding it as a javascript string would yield:

```
src="?ajax=1&cls=owAjaxHandler&mtd=thumbnail&amp;i=wp-content/uploads/2011/07/Bahrija &amp; Fomm ir-rih08.jpg&amp;w=115&amp;h=115"
```

Comment: I edited the post to show the decoded string better (for comparison). I'm not sure what you're saying but it doesn't look wrong to me. I still fail to understand why Chrome tries to parse a URL out of straight Javascript. While at it, couldn't this prove to be a good attack vector on locked-down javascript systems (like facebook API)?

Comment: @Christian: are you sure it's Chrome that's parsing those strings directly?  Or are they parsed by google map's api when the `new` is called?

Comment: I can't be 100% sure, but I've had this issue elsewhere where there wasn't Google maps. Besides, this is taking place regardless if Google Maps has been initialized or not.

Comment: Also, I've checked out the "generated code" and the malformed content doesn't show up in the DOM anywhere. If, instead, the code attempted to get the images through some other method, it would show up in the console and it could be traced (but, alas, this is not happening).

Comment: They wouldn't show up in the console per se. Do you mean the Network panel? Also, can you replace the code in your question with a SSCCE? http://sscce.org/

Comment: It shows up in the console as well. The console also reports file read error (anything 4xx or 5xx).